# rails devise wrong number of arguments in if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, if-statement, devise

In the following code, I'm trying to check whether all current_user fields are filled and, if not, take steps to fix that.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base   
  before_action  :configure_premitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :check_status

  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.   
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.     
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  private

  def configure_premitted_parameters  
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) << [:email, :password]  
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [:email, :password, :password_confirmation]  
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << [:email, :age, :gender, :fullname, :familyStatus, :about, :current_password, :new_password, :new_password_confirmation]   
  end

  def check_status
    if current_user(:age || :gender || :fullname || :familyStatus || :about ).empty?
      redirect_to edit_user_password
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end 
  end

end
```

I'm getting this error:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

From line

> if current_user(:age || :gender || :fullname || :familyStatus ||
>   :about ).empty?

Could you explain what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the syntax you're using in the if statement in the check_status method. And given that you're getting an argument error and that's the only if statement which takes an argument I'm guessing that's the offending line.

I'd be inclined to move that big if clause into another method which communicates your intentions better. What exactly are you trying to check with that if statement? If you want to check that at all those fields are completed, the following would work.

```
def check_status
  if current_user_incomplete?
    redirect_to edit_user_password
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end 
end

def incomplete_current_user?
  [current_user.age, current_user.gender, current_user.fullname, current_user.familyStatus, current_user.about].all?
end
```

Next time you post, please provide more specific information about the error e.g. which line is causing the error.

Comment: thank you it worked , and i will post next time more info sorry about the fuzz but thank you for the help :)

Comment: tho its not redirecting for some reason

Comment: nvm fixed it changed .all? to .present?